# How to use fragments in Android 2.3 GingerBread?

Tags: android, fragment, compatibility, android-2.3-gingerbread

I am developing an android application that must run on Android 2.3.3 onwards. Is it possible to use fragments on this application since fragments are not supported on pre honeycomb versions? If possible how?

Comment: You mark the answer as accepted for other users.

Answer (score 3):

**Use fragment V4**

**android-support-v4.jar available in ref-lib folder**

if not available add from

**../android-sdks/extras/android-support-v4.jar**

Extents **fragment** and **import android.support.v4.Fragment**
write to code**

hope it helps...

Comment: One comment, if you use support library, then use it for all you project. Don't use both support and native realizations.

Comment: Use import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;

Answer (score 0):

use support Library [Actionbarsherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/samples.html) or [Support Library](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/index.html) .. Support Library [tutorial](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android-compatibility-working-with-fragments--mobile-5431)